# Python Flask URL Logic for 2 different scripts and different views

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am new to flask(using it with nginx) and I am trying to understand the URL logic. I have 2 python scripts.... /site/myapp.py and /site/bar.py.

I have three questions, please:

1. If, I want to run myapp.py only and not /site/bar.py how do I add
   a url rule to run it with add_url_rule?
2. How would I do the same if I wanted to run
       /site/bar.py instead?
3. If I wanted to run myapp.py, and have two
       different views...depending on `xml.open("POST",
       "/site/myapp/view1", true)` and  `xml.open("POST",
       "/site/myapp/view2"`, true)....how would I assign a url for the each
       view in myapp.py with add_url_rule?

python script /site/myapp.py:

```
root@chat:/site# cat myapp.py
import flask, flask.views
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

class View1(flask.views.MethodView):
    def post(self):
    pass

app.add_url_rule('/site/myapp', view_func=View1.as_view('view1'))

root@chat:/site#
```

Javascript function:

```
function foo() {
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("POST", "/site/myapp", true);
        xml.send(form);
        console.log("sent")
        xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log(xml.readyState);
            console.log(xml.status);
            if (xml.readyState == "4" && xml.status == "200"){
                console.log("yes");
                console.log(xml.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 10.33.113.55;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

location / {
root /var/www/dude;
}

location /site/ {
       try_files $uri @uwsgi;
}

location @uwsgi {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    }

}
```

Comment: Flask doesn't have a CGI- or PHP-like routing system. The URL scheme can look completely different than the filesystem structure. Please start out with either the [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) or the [Tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

On the [flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/), you can find things like:

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

That means, anyone accessing your website at `http://yourdomain.tld/` will execute the `show_entries` function and the returned value of `render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)` will be sent to the user.

On [this page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/), you can also find that:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

You need to forget about your PHP background, and think in another way. People won't access you website using URLs like `http://yourdomain.com/index.py`. Basically, you tell your server that flask is in charge of handling the URLs, and you map URLs to functions. Simple as that.